# How to keep the dictionary up to date when using a generator?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

When I am using a generator, even I modify the dictionary passed to it, the generator still gives me a result with the old data structure.
How could I fix that?

```
def min_key_order(adict:dict):
    for key, value in sorted(adict.items()):
        yield (key, value)

d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}
i = min_key_order(d)
print(next(i))
d.pop(2)
print(next(i))
```

And it gives me `(1,'a')`, `(2,'x')`, even I have pop key 2 from the dictionary.

Comment: You can't iterate over a dictionary that you alter. That's unsupported behaviour.

Comment: However, the `sorted()` function produces a **new list**; that list is not going to be updated to follow changes in the original dicitonary.

Comment: Neither of these has anything to do with generators, you get the same behaviour if you put your `d.pop()` inside a `for` loop over `sorted(d)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your generator is not iterating over the dictionary. It is iterating over a new list object that `sorted()` returned:

```
>>> d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}
>>> l = sorted(d.items())
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'x', 4: 'm', 8: 'd', 16: 'f'}
>>> l
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'x'), (4, 'm'), (8, 'd'), (16, 'f')]
>>> d.pop(2)
'x'
>>> l
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'x'), (4, 'm'), (8, 'd'), (16, 'f')]
```

Removing items from the dictionary can't update the new list; that structure is not a live view on the dictionary.

For that to work, you'd have to *re-sort* the dictionary each and every iteration, and keep track of an iteration position:

```
def sorted_view(d):
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(d):
        yield sorted(d.items())[pos]
        pos += 1
```

This is hugely inefficient; sorting is a relatively expensive operation.

A more efficient method would be to store *just the keys* in sorted order, and then *test* if the key is still available:

```
def min_key_order(adict:dict):
    for key in sorted(adict):
        if key in adict:
            yield (key, adict[key])
```

This will however not detect if you *added* more keys.